# Not able to get hazelcast map statistics by python script

Tags: python, hazelcast

### Script:

```
import hazelcast, logging
from time import sleep

config = hazelcast.ClientConfig()
config.network_config.addresses.append('localhost:5701')                                    


logging.basicConfig()
logging.getLogger().setLevel(logging.INFO)

client = hazelcast.HazelcastClient(config)
my_map = client.get_map("map-name").blocking()

my_map.put("key_1", "value_1")
value = my_map.get("key_1")
print("Get val :"+value)
print("map.contains_key", my_map.contains_key("key"))
print("map.get", my_map.get("key"))
print("map.size", my_map.size())
print("map.putcount", my_map.get("putCount"))

client.shutdown()
```

I want to get the hazelcast map statistics by python (which will done in java by getLocalMapStats() method). Is there any such method to get all the stats by python.I'm able to connect and put and get values from hazelcast cluster but not able to get hazelcast map statistics, please suggest

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it's not there for python client, yet. Please create an issue here: https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast-python-client/issues and also feel free to contribute if possible.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. Is this available in REST API's?.

Comment: REST client is not as advanced as other clients of Hazelcast, but you can use something like jolokia to establish a REST-like access to per member JMX and get the stats exposed through jmx. See: http://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/3.10/manual/html-single/#jmx-api-per-member